# Issues while Parsing json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, listview

I want to parse json for past cruise and display the data inside list view. I am getting this exception while parsing. Unhandled Exception: type 'CrusieModel' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Also when i try to display the data inside listview it shows Null operator called on null value at itemCount.

My API class

```
 final String baseUrl = "https://yourapilink";
  String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCIsImtleSI6MjAxNzA5MjEsImlhdCI6MTYzMDk1MzAzNCiZXhwIjoxNjMxNTU3ODM0LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vYXBwLWFwaS5mcmVb2xzZW5jcnVpc2VzLmNvbSJ9.eyJSb2xlcyI6WyJNeUNydWlzZSJdLCJab2hvSUQiOiIyOTIxMTwMDAwMDAyODMwODgifQ.OCjwy_Q8mWaJUBWTIzAfUvX4voMDdry_Y_LLj6s8nxt514BVNQk3yptcZFnD48Hd";
 
  Future<CrusieModel> getPastCruise( BuildContext context, String? token) async {

    String url = baseUrl + "api/v1/atcore/user?token=$token";
    //Utilities.showLoaderDialog(context);
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization':'Bearer $token'
    });

    debugPrint("jsonBody past and future:::: ${response.body}");
    print("jsonBody past and future:::: ${response.body}");
    print("nntoken::: $token");
    print("response Code cruise history:::: ${response.statusCode}");
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      //Navigator.pop(context);
      // return json.decode(response.body);
      return CrusieModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else if(response.statusCode == 500){
      //Navigator.pop(context);
      return Utilities.errorDialog("There was an error getting the information from Atcore or Zoho", context);
    }else{
      //Navigator.pop(context);
      return Utilities.errorDialog("Something went wrong", context);
    }
    // return data;

  }
```

My Model Class

```
import 'dart:convert';

CrusieModel crusieModelFromJson(String str) => CrusieModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String crusieModelToJson(CrusieModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CrusieModel {
  CrusieModel({
    this.pastCruises,
  });

  List<PastCruise>? pastCruises;

  factory CrusieModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CrusieModel(
    pastCruises: List<PastCruise>.from(json["PastCruises"].map((x) => PastCruise.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "PastCruises": List<dynamic>.from(pastCruises!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class PastCruise {
  PastCruise({
    this.cruiseId,
    this.name,
    this.shortName,
    this.departureDate,
    this.returnDate,
    this.duration,
    this.shortDescription,
    this.departurePortCode,
    this.departurePortName,
    this.departurePortNameWithCountry,
    this.returnPortCode,
    this.returnPortName,
    this.returnPortNameWithCountry,
    this.shipCode,
    this.shipName,
    this.cruiseStatus,
    this.cruiseStatusApp,
    this.cruisingCategory,
    this.cruiseCancelledInfo,
    this.modifiedDate,
    this.isAddOnHoliday,
    this.bookingRef,
    this.agentName,
    this.guests,
  });

  String? cruiseId;
  String? name;
  String? shortName;
  DateTime? departureDate;
  DateTime? returnDate;
  int? duration;
  String? shortDescription;
  String? departurePortCode;
  String? departurePortName;
  String? departurePortNameWithCountry;
  String? returnPortCode;
  String? returnPortName;
  String? returnPortNameWithCountry;
  String? shipCode;
  String? shipName;
  String? cruiseStatus;
  String? cruiseStatusApp;
  String? cruisingCategory;
  String? cruiseCancelledInfo;
  DateTime? modifiedDate;
  bool? isAddOnHoliday;
  String? bookingRef;
  String? agentName;
  String? guests;

  factory PastCruise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PastCruise(
    cruiseId: json["CruiseId"],
    name: json["Name"],
    shortName: json["ShortName"],
    departureDate: DateTime.parse(json["DepartureDate"]),
    returnDate: DateTime.parse(json["ReturnDate"]),
    duration: json["Duration"],
    shortDescription: json["ShortDescription"],
    departurePortCode: json["DeparturePortCode"],
    departurePortName: json["DeparturePortName"],
    departurePortNameWithCountry: json["DeparturePortNameWithCountry"],
    returnPortCode: json["ReturnPortCode"],
    returnPortName: json["ReturnPortName"],
    returnPortNameWithCountry: json["ReturnPortNameWithCountry"],
    shipCode: json["ShipCode"],
    shipName: json["ShipName"],
    cruiseStatus: json["CruiseStatus"],
    cruiseStatusApp: json["CruiseStatusApp"],
    cruisingCategory: json["CruisingCategory"],
    cruiseCancelledInfo: json["CruiseCancelledInfo"],
    modifiedDate: DateTime.parse(json["ModifiedDate"]),
    isAddOnHoliday: json["IsAddOnHoliday"],
    bookingRef: json["BookingRef"],
    agentName: json["AgentName"],
    guests: json["Guests"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CruiseId": cruiseId,
    "Name": name,
    "ShortName": shortName,
    "DepartureDate": departureDate!.toIso8601String(),
    "ReturnDate": returnDate!.toIso8601String(),
    "Duration": duration,
    "ShortDescription": shortDescription,
    "DeparturePortCode": departurePortCode,
    "DeparturePortName": departurePortName,
    "DeparturePortNameWithCountry": departurePortNameWithCountry,
    "ReturnPortCode": returnPortCode,
    "ReturnPortName": returnPortName,
    "ReturnPortNameWithCountry": returnPortNameWithCountry,
    "ShipCode": shipCode,
    "ShipName": shipName,
    "CruiseStatus": cruiseStatus,
    "CruiseStatusApp": cruiseStatusApp,
    "CruisingCategory": cruisingCategory,
    "CruiseCancelledInfo": cruiseCancelledInfo,
    "ModifiedDate": modifiedDate!.toIso8601String(),
    "IsAddOnHoliday": isAddOnHoliday,
    "BookingRef": bookingRef,
    "AgentName": agentName,
    "Guests": guests,
  };
}
```

My Listview Widget

At    `itemCount: snapshot.data!.pastCruises!.length,` I am getting Null Check operator used on null value

```
  Widget listviewWidget(){
    return FutureBuilder<CrusieModel>(
      future: pastCruises,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        log("${snapshot.data}", name: "DATA RECEIVED");
        /*  if(snapshot.hasData){*/
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.pastCruises!.length,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                CrusieModel cruiseData = snapshot.data! ;

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                  child:
                  Stack(

                    children: [
                      Image.asset("assets/images/ticket_bg.png",
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.35,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.90,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                      Container(

                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.90,
                        child: Column(

                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(

                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.15,

                              child:  Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50, top: 30),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(

                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text("Departure", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                            color: CustomColors.subtitleText, fontSize: 12),),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(/*items[index].departureDate*/"25",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 32),),
                                            Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(/*items[index].departureDateMonth*/"08",
                                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),),
                                                Text(/*items[index].departureDateYear*/"2008",
                                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
                                        Text("${cruiseData.pastCruises?[index].duration ?? ""}", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Return', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText, fontSize: 12),),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(/*items[index].returnDate*/"18",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 32),),
                                            Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(/*items[index].returnDateMonth*/"03",
                                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),),
                                                Text(/*items[index].returnDateYear*/"2019",
                                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 20, 50, 30),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text("Passenger", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText, fontSize: 12),),
                                            Text("/*items[index].passengerName*/""amit kumar", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                                          ],),
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text("Booking Reference", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText, fontSize: 12),),
                                            Text("${cruiseData.pastCruises![index].bookingRef}", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                                          ],)
                                      ],),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text("TRavel Agency", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.subtitleText, fontSize: 12),),
                                            Text("${cruiseData.pastCruises![index].agentName}", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: CustomColors.madison,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                                          ],),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10,)
                                      ],)

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            )

                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),

                );
              });
        /*}else{
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }*/

      },

    );
  }
```

I am not getting what is the issue here. I just want to display past cruise parameters in a listview.

Comment: have you tested the request with Postman ?

Comment: what is the responce.body?

Comment: Mhmd Zawi Yes i have tested its working

Comment: HasanToufiqAhamed Shall i update response body here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fist i proved the output**

[image]

**Code:**

```
  final String baseUrl = "https://appservice-staging.simpleclick.co.uk/";
  String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4N";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPastCruise();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: yourModelName!.futureCruises!.length,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(yourModelName!.futureCruises![index].duration!.toString()),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  getPastCruise() async {
    String url = '${baseUrl}api/v1/atcore/user?token=$token';
    //Utilities.showLoaderDialog(context);
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Authorization':'Bearer $token'
    });

    if(response.statusCode==200){
      setState(() {
        yourModelName=YourModelName.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
```

**YourModelName.dart**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final yourModelName = yourModelNameFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

YourModelName yourModelNameFromJson(String str) => YourModelName.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String yourModelNameToJson(YourModelName data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class YourModelName {
  YourModelName({
    this.oceans,
    this.pastCruises,
    this.futureCruises,
  });

  Oceans? oceans;
  List<PastCruise>? pastCruises;
  List<FutureCruise>? futureCruises;

  factory YourModelName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => YourModelName(
    oceans: Oceans.fromJson(json["Oceans"]),
    pastCruises: List<PastCruise>.from(json["PastCruises"].map((x) => PastCruise.fromJson(x))),
    futureCruises: List<FutureCruise>.from(json["FutureCruises"].map((x) => FutureCruise.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Oceans": oceans!.toJson(),
    "PastCruises": List<dynamic>.from(pastCruises!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "FutureCruises": List<dynamic>.from(futureCruises!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class FutureCruise {
  FutureCruise({
    this.cruiseId,
    this.name,
    this.shortName,
    this.departureDate,
    this.returnDate,
    this.duration,
    this.shortDescription,
    this.departurePortCode,
    this.departurePortName,
    this.departurePortNameWithCountry,
    this.returnPortCode,
    this.returnPortName,
    this.returnPortNameWithCountry,
    this.shipCode,
    this.shipName,
    this.cruiseStatus,
    this.cruiseStatusApp,
    this.cruisingCategory,
    this.cruiseCancelledInfo,
    this.modifiedDate,
    this.bookingRef,
    this.bookedDate,
    this.agentName,
    this.fareTypeId,
    this.fareDescription,
    this.fareCode,
    this.guests,
    this.theme,
    this.portTerminal,
    this.gifMissing,
    this.flights,
    this.cabins,
  });

  CruiseId? cruiseId;
  Name? name;
  Name? shortName;
  DateTime? departureDate;
  DateTime? returnDate;
  int? duration;
  String? shortDescription;
  PortCode? departurePortCode;
  PortName? departurePortName;
  PortNameWithCountry? departurePortNameWithCountry;
  PortCode? returnPortCode;
  PortName? returnPortName;
  PortNameWithCountry? returnPortNameWithCountry;
  ShipCode? shipCode;
  ShipName? shipName;
  CruiseStatus? cruiseStatus;
  String? cruiseStatusApp;
  CruisingCategory? cruisingCategory;
  String? cruiseCancelledInfo;
  DateTime? modifiedDate;
  String? bookingRef;
  DateTime? bookedDate;
  AgentName? agentName;
  FareTypeId? fareTypeId;
  FareDescription? fareDescription;
  FareCode? fareCode;
  Guest? guests;
  Theme? theme;
  PortTerminal? portTerminal;
  bool? gifMissing;
  List<dynamic>? flights;
  List<Cabin>? cabins;

  factory FutureCruise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FutureCruise(
    cruiseId: cruiseIdValues.map[json["CruiseId"]],
    name: nameValues.map[json["Name"]],
    shortName: nameValues.map[json["ShortName"]],
    departureDate: DateTime.parse(json["DepartureDate"]),
    returnDate: DateTime.parse(json["ReturnDate"]),
    duration: json["Duration"],
    shortDescription: json["ShortDescription"],
    departurePortCode: portCodeValues.map[json["DeparturePortCode"]],
    departurePortName: portNameValues.map[json["DeparturePortName"]],
    departurePortNameWithCountry: portNameWithCountryValues.map[json["DeparturePortNameWithCountry"]],
    returnPortCode: portCodeValues.map[json["ReturnPortCode"]],
    returnPortName: portNameValues.map[json["ReturnPortName"]],
    returnPortNameWithCountry: portNameWithCountryValues.map[json["ReturnPortNameWithCountry"]],
    shipCode: shipCodeValues.map[json["ShipCode"]],
    shipName: shipNameValues.map[json["ShipName"]],
    cruiseStatus: cruiseStatusValues.map[json["CruiseStatus"]],
    cruiseStatusApp: json["CruiseStatusApp"],
    cruisingCategory: cruisingCategoryValues.map[json["CruisingCategory"]],
    cruiseCancelledInfo: json["CruiseCancelledInfo"],
    modifiedDate: DateTime.parse(json["ModifiedDate"]),
    bookingRef: json["BookingRef"],
    bookedDate: DateTime.parse(json["BookedDate"]),
    agentName: agentNameValues.map[json["AgentName"]],
    fareTypeId: fareTypeIdValues.map[json["FareTypeId"]],
    fareDescription: fareDescriptionValues.map[json["FareDescription"]],
    fareCode: fareCodeValues.map[json["FareCode"]],
    guests: guestValues.map[json["Guests"]],
    theme: themeValues.map[json["Theme"]],
    portTerminal: portTerminalValues.map[json["PortTerminal"]],
    gifMissing: json["GIFMissing"],
    flights: List<dynamic>.from(json["Flights"].map((x) => x)),
    cabins: List<Cabin>.from(json["Cabins"].map((x) => Cabin.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CruiseId": cruiseIdValues.reverse[cruiseId],
    "Name": nameValues.reverse[name],
    "ShortName": nameValues.reverse[shortName],
    "Duration": duration,
    "ShortDescription": shortDescription,
    "DeparturePortCode": portCodeValues.reverse[departurePortCode],
    "DeparturePortName": portNameValues.reverse[departurePortName],
    "DeparturePortNameWithCountry": portNameWithCountryValues.reverse[departurePortNameWithCountry],
    "ReturnPortCode": portCodeValues.reverse[returnPortCode],
    "ReturnPortName": portNameValues.reverse[returnPortName],
    "ReturnPortNameWithCountry": portNameWithCountryValues.reverse[returnPortNameWithCountry],
    "ShipCode": shipCodeValues.reverse[shipCode],
    "ShipName": shipNameValues.reverse[shipName],
    "CruiseStatus": cruiseStatusValues.reverse[cruiseStatus],
    "CruiseStatusApp": cruiseStatusApp,
    "CruisingCategory": cruisingCategoryValues.reverse[cruisingCategory],
    "CruiseCancelledInfo": cruiseCancelledInfo,
    "BookingRef": bookingRef,
    "AgentName": agentNameValues.reverse[agentName],
    "FareTypeId": fareTypeIdValues.reverse[fareTypeId],
    "FareDescription": fareDescriptionValues.reverse[fareDescription],
    "FareCode": fareCodeValues.reverse[fareCode],
    "Guests": guestValues.reverse[guests],
    "Theme": themeValues.reverse[theme],
    "PortTerminal": portTerminalValues.reverse[portTerminal],
    "GIFMissing": gifMissing,
    "Flights": List<dynamic>.from(flights!.map((x) => x)),
    "Cabins": List<dynamic>.from(cabins!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

enum AgentName { DIRECT, F9255, THE_0_F1234 }

final agentNameValues = EnumValues({
  "DIRECT": AgentName.DIRECT,
  "F9255": AgentName.F9255,
  "0F1234": AgentName.THE_0_F1234
});

class Cabin {
  Cabin({
    this.cabinNumber,
    this.deckId,
    this.cabinGrade,
    this.referenceNos,
    this.guestNames,
    this.checkInTime,
    this.checkInCloses,
  });

  String? cabinNumber;
  String? deckId;
  String? cabinGrade;
  String? referenceNos;
  Guest? guestNames;
  String? checkInTime;
  String? checkInCloses;

  factory Cabin.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cabin(
    cabinNumber: json["CabinNumber"],
    deckId: json["DeckId"],
    cabinGrade: json["CabinGrade"],
    referenceNos: json["ReferenceNos"],
    guestNames: guestValues.map[json["GuestNames"]],
    checkInTime: json["CheckInTime"],
    checkInCloses: json["CheckInCloses"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CabinNumber": cabinNumber,
    "DeckId": deckId,
    "CabinGrade": cabinGrade,
    "ReferenceNos": referenceNos,
    "GuestNames": guestValues.reverse[guestNames],
    "CheckInTime": checkInTime,
    "CheckInCloses": checkInCloses,
  };
}

enum Guest { TEST_USER_JONATHAN_QUINNELL, EMPTY }

final guestValues = EnumValues({
  "": Guest.EMPTY,
  "Test User, Jonathan Quinnell": Guest.TEST_USER_JONATHAN_QUINNELL
});

enum CruiseId { T2122, S2124, T2129, L2222 }

final cruiseIdValues = EnumValues({
  "L2222": CruiseId.L2222,
  "S2124": CruiseId.S2124,
  "T2122": CruiseId.T2122,
  "T2129": CruiseId.T2129
});

enum CruiseStatus { ACTIVE }

final cruiseStatusValues = EnumValues({
  "Active": CruiseStatus.ACTIVE
});

enum CruisingCategory { OCEAN }

final cruisingCategoryValues = EnumValues({
  "Ocean": CruisingCategory.OCEAN
});

enum PortCode { GBDVR, GBLIV, GBSOU, GBROY }

final portCodeValues = EnumValues({
  "GBDVR": PortCode.GBDVR,
  "GBLIV": PortCode.GBLIV,
  "GBROY": PortCode.GBROY,
  "GBSOU": PortCode.GBSOU
});

enum PortName { DOVER, LIVERPOOL, SOUTHAMPTON, ROSYTH_EDINBURGH }

final portNameValues = EnumValues({
  "Dover": PortName.DOVER,
  "Liverpool": PortName.LIVERPOOL,
  "Rosyth (Edinburgh)": PortName.ROSYTH_EDINBURGH,
  "Southampton": PortName.SOUTHAMPTON
});

enum PortNameWithCountry { DOVER_ENGLAND, LIVERPOOL_ENGLAND, SOUTHAMPTON_ENGLAND, ROSYTH_EDINBURGH_SCOTLAND }

final portNameWithCountryValues = EnumValues({
  "Dover,  England": PortNameWithCountry.DOVER_ENGLAND,
  "Liverpool, England": PortNameWithCountry.LIVERPOOL_ENGLAND,
  "Rosyth (Edinburgh), Scotland": PortNameWithCountry.ROSYTH_EDINBURGH_SCOTLAND,
  "Southampton, England": PortNameWithCountry.SOUTHAMPTON_ENGLAND
});

enum FareCode { F_F_1, EMPTY }

final fareCodeValues = EnumValues({
  "": FareCode.EMPTY,
  "F-F-1": FareCode.F_F_1
});

enum FareDescription { FREEDOM_FARE, EMPTY }

final fareDescriptionValues = EnumValues({
  "": FareDescription.EMPTY,
  "Freedom Fare": FareDescription.FREEDOM_FARE
});

enum FareTypeId { F, EMPTY }

final fareTypeIdValues = EnumValues({
  "": FareTypeId.EMPTY,
  "F": FareTypeId.F
});

enum Name { SWEDISH_WATERWAYS_WITH_A_TASTE_OF_DENMARK, EXPLORING_THE_AZORES_AND_PORTUGAL, LANDSCAPES_OF_THE_CANARY_ISLANDS, BLACK_SEA_DISCOVERY_MEDITERRANEAN_ADVENTURE }

final nameValues = EnumValues({
  "Black Sea Discovery & Mediterranean Adventure": Name.BLACK_SEA_DISCOVERY_MEDITERRANEAN_ADVENTURE,
  "Exploring the Azores and Portugal": Name.EXPLORING_THE_AZORES_AND_PORTUGAL,
  "Landscapes of the Canary Islands": Name.LANDSCAPES_OF_THE_CANARY_ISLANDS,
  "Swedish Waterways with a Taste of Denmark": Name.SWEDISH_WATERWAYS_WITH_A_TASTE_OF_DENMARK
});

enum PortTerminal { CRUISE_TERMINAL_2, ACC_EXHIBITION_CENTRE, EMPTY }

final portTerminalValues = EnumValues({
  "ACC Exhibition Centre": PortTerminal.ACC_EXHIBITION_CENTRE,
  "Cruise Terminal 2": PortTerminal.CRUISE_TERMINAL_2,
  "": PortTerminal.EMPTY
});

enum ShipCode { BT, BS, BL }

final shipCodeValues = EnumValues({
  "BL": ShipCode.BL,
  "BS": ShipCode.BS,
  "BT": ShipCode.BT
});

enum ShipName { BOLETTE, BOREALIS, BALMORAL }

final shipNameValues = EnumValues({
  "Balmoral": ShipName.BALMORAL,
  "Bolette": ShipName.BOLETTE,
  "Borealis": ShipName.BOREALIS
});

enum Theme { THE_12_X_FORMAL_EVENINGS, THE_13_X_FORMAL_EVENINGS, EMPTY }

final themeValues = EnumValues({
  "": Theme.EMPTY,
  "1. 2 x Formal Evenings": Theme.THE_12_X_FORMAL_EVENINGS,
  "1. 3 x Formal Evenings": Theme.THE_13_X_FORMAL_EVENINGS
});

class Oceans {
  Oceans({
    this.number,
    this.status,
    this.type,
    this.points,
  });

  dynamic? number;
  dynamic? status;
  String? type;
  int? points;

  factory Oceans.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Oceans(
    number: json["Number"],
    status: json["Status"],
    type: json["Type"],
    points: json["Points"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Number": number,
    "Status": status,
    "Type": type,
    "Points": points,
  };
}

class PastCruise {
  PastCruise({
    this.cruiseId,
    this.name,
    this.shortName,
    this.departureDate,
    this.returnDate,
    this.duration,
    this.shortDescription,
    this.departurePortCode,
    this.departurePortName,
    this.departurePortNameWithCountry,
    this.returnPortCode,
    this.returnPortName,
    this.returnPortNameWithCountry,
    this.shipCode,
    this.shipName,
    this.cruiseStatus,
    this.cruiseStatusApp,
    this.cruisingCategory,
    this.cruiseCancelledInfo,
    this.modifiedDate,
    this.isAddOnHoliday,
    this.bookingRef,
    this.agentName,
    this.guests,
  });

  String? cruiseId;
  String? name;
  String? shortName;
  DateTime? departureDate;
  DateTime? returnDate;
  int? duration;
  String? shortDescription;
  PortCode? departurePortCode;
  PortName? departurePortName;
  PortNameWithCountry? departurePortNameWithCountry;
  PortCode? returnPortCode;
  PortName? returnPortName;
  PortNameWithCountry? returnPortNameWithCountry;
  String? shipCode;
  String? shipName;
  String? cruiseStatus;
  String? cruiseStatusApp;
  CruisingCategory? cruisingCategory;
  String? cruiseCancelledInfo;
  DateTime? modifiedDate;
  bool? isAddOnHoliday;
  String? bookingRef;
  String? agentName;
  String? guests;

  factory PastCruise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PastCruise(
    cruiseId: json["CruiseId"],
    name: json["Name"],
    shortName: json["ShortName"],
    departureDate: DateTime.parse(json["DepartureDate"]),
    returnDate: DateTime.parse(json["ReturnDate"]),
    duration: json["Duration"],
    shortDescription: json["ShortDescription"],
    departurePortCode: portCodeValues.map[json["DeparturePortCode"]],
    departurePortName: portNameValues.map[json["DeparturePortName"]],
    departurePortNameWithCountry: portNameWithCountryValues.map[json["DeparturePortNameWithCountry"]],
    returnPortCode: portCodeValues.map[json["ReturnPortCode"]],
    returnPortName: portNameValues.map[json["ReturnPortName"]],
    returnPortNameWithCountry: portNameWithCountryValues.map[json["ReturnPortNameWithCountry"]],
    shipCode: json["ShipCode"],
    shipName: json["ShipName"],
    cruiseStatus: json["CruiseStatus"],
    cruiseStatusApp: json["CruiseStatusApp"],
    cruisingCategory: cruisingCategoryValues.map[json["CruisingCategory"]],
    cruiseCancelledInfo: json["CruiseCancelledInfo"],
    modifiedDate: DateTime.parse(json["ModifiedDate"]),
    isAddOnHoliday: json["IsAddOnHoliday"],
    bookingRef: json["BookingRef"],
    agentName: json["AgentName"],
    guests: json["Guests"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "CruiseId": cruiseId,
    "Name": name,
    "ShortName": shortName,
    "Duration": duration,
    "ShortDescription": shortDescription,
    "DeparturePortCode": portCodeValues.reverse[departurePortCode],
    "DeparturePortName": portNameValues.reverse[departurePortName],
    "DeparturePortNameWithCountry": portNameWithCountryValues.reverse[departurePortNameWithCountry],
    "ReturnPortCode": portCodeValues.reverse[returnPortCode],
    "ReturnPortName": portNameValues.reverse[returnPortName],
    "ReturnPortNameWithCountry": portNameWithCountryValues.reverse[returnPortNameWithCountry],
    "ShipCode": shipCode,
    "ShipName": shipName,
    "CruiseStatus": cruiseStatus,
    "CruiseStatusApp": cruiseStatusApp,
    "CruisingCategory": cruisingCategoryValues.reverse[cruisingCategory],
    "CruiseCancelledInfo": cruiseCancelledInfo,
    "IsAddOnHoliday": isAddOnHoliday,
    "BookingRef": bookingRef,
    "AgentName": agentName,
    "Guests": guests,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

Comment: It shows the response body but when i try to display it on listview.builder it always shows null. Ill update my listview code.

Comment: I have updated my listview widget and line in which i am getting error.

Comment: you need to design own list. for example i placed the futureCruises duration only. and full of code are use null safety

Comment: Thank you show much it worked! What was the issue exactly?

Comment: HasanToufiqAhamed Please remove baseUrl from your code to avoid any miss-use.

Comment: @VinayBakle i do the change